# program that store integer values into a 2D array

Tags: c, for-loop

It just creates random values

I tried using a separate value for the variable of the array and I also don't know why it starts counting at element 6.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i;
int array[3][5];

for (i = 0; i<5; i++);
    {
    printf("Input a whole number for row 1 element %d:\n", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &array[0][i]);
    }

printf("Row 1 elements:\n");
for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", array[0][i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Ouput:

```
> Input a whole number for row 1 element 6: 4 Row 1 elements: 0 0 0 0
> 1897665488
> 
> Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.969 s Press any key to
> continue.
```

Comment: I'm curious about the semicolon at the end of this line: `for (i = 0; i<5; i++);` What if you deleted that semicolon?

Comment: look, you have 2 dimensional array - i.e. tensor. For better understanding, if you already ok with [data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) conception. Array of arrays. i.e. each variable of such array - is another array. What does it means int array[3][5]; - array of 3 elements, each element is another array of 5 ints. So to iterate over the tensor you'll need two level loop.

Comment: `for(size_t i=0; i < 3; i++) {
   cprintf("|%d", array[i][0]);
   for(size_t j=1; j < 5; j++) {
     cprintf(", %d", array[i][j]);
   } cprintf(" |\n");}`

Comment: @VictorGubin: The function `cprintf` is not part of the ISO C standard library, but is a platform-specific function. Note that the question is not tagged with any particular platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It starts counting from `6` because the line `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++);`, is iterating (incrementing) `i` 5 times so, `i` becomes `5`, then you print `i + 1` to `stdout`.

So, basically your call to `printf()` and `scanf()` functions were never a part of any sort of loop.

*NOTE: Adding a semi-colon `;`, after any [loop](https://www.w3schools.in/cplusplus-tutorial/loops/) means that there is no body for the loop. Basically it's an empty loop. It can be useful for finding the length of a string, and so on.*

##### Some tips:

- Also instead to using bare `return 0;`, use `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`, which is defined in the header file `stdlib.h`.
- use `int main(void) { }`, instead of `int main() { }`
- always check whether `scanf()` input was successful or not

#### Correct Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int array[3][5];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Input a whole number for row 1 element %d:\n", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%d", &array[0][i]) != 1)
        {
            perror("bad input: only numbers are acceptable\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    printf("Row 1 elements:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[0][i]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### Output:

```
Input a whole number for row 1 element 1:
1
Input a whole number for row 1 element 2:
2
Input a whole number for row 1 element 3:
3
Input a whole number for row 1 element 4:
5
Input a whole number for row 1 element 5:
7
Row 1 elements:
1
2
3
5
7
```